# Wait for Observable response with if condition in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I am facing issue with Observable. Writing the problem statement.

I am receiving an order from a customer with PO number but some time customer order missing PO number so i just create temp PO number and fill it in form and receive order. but when i call temp PO number create service it does not wait for response. Check code below.

> Only call `this._partReceivingService.generateTempPo()` service if condition matched and fill respose in form data else there will be filled customer PO by user

```
if (this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value == true) {
       this._partReceivingService.generateTempPo().subscribe(res=>{
          this.partRecevingForm.controls.customerOrderNumber.setValue(res.tempPONo);
      })
  }
//then i am executing receiving order service
this._partReceivingService.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
   //notifications
})
```

Comment: Tell me if am wrong, this service `this._partReceivingService.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value)` will be invoked in both cases, means even there is no `this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value` ? but in other hand, if that condition is fulfilled , you want to wait for the response before invoking it ?

Comment: @selemmn it will only execute if `this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value`  has true value otherwise it will not execute

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
  receiveNewPart(value) {
    //then i am executing receiving order service
    this._partReceivingService.receiveNewPart(value).subscribe(
      (data)=>   {
                  //notifications
                })
  }


  if (this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value === true) {
       this._partReceivingService.generateTempPo().subscribe(res=>{
          this.partRecevingForm.controls.customerOrderNumber.setValue(res.tempPONo);
          this.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value) // --> here PO number is what u're waiting for.
      })
  } else {
    this.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value) // --> here temp PO number
  }
```

Comment: This is only solution i can follow because i have writen long code in `this.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value)` subscribe method so same code i have to write in if and else condition.

Comment: when i subscribe `this.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value)` this service i am calling some other servicer under subscribe so the same code i have to write in if and else condition both. Are you getting my point?

Comment: @Bharat That's why i'd exported the service into a separated method this.receiveNewPart, so you wont rewrite it every time, else you have not another choice AFAIK, that's ur logic that led to this, and I do not see a bad implementation here frankly. :) BTW only one service will be invoked , there's `if -- else`.

Answer (score 0):

Observables work asynchronously. When you call them, there is a part of your code that will wait for that to finish but the rest of your code will continue to run. For example this function

```
myFunc() {
    console.log('hello 1');
    this.myservice.getSomething().subscribe(() => console.log('hello 2'));
    console.log('hello 3');
}
```

will produce this in the console

```
> hello 1
> hello 3
> hello 2
```

So you will have to put your second service call inside the `subscribe` of your first service call. Also, I would suggest using the `patchValue()` instead of the `controls.fieldName.setValue()`

```
if (this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value == true) {
       this._partReceivingService.generateTempPo().subscribe(res=>{
          this.partRecevingForm.patchValue({customerOrderNumber: res.tempPONo});

          this._partReceivingService.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
             //notifications
          });
      });
} else {
    this._partReceivingService.receiveNewPart(this.partRecevingForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
      //notifications
    })
 }
```

Comment: if `this.partRecevingForm.controls.ShipperHasNoPO.value` false then in else condition i have to call create order service again and this is something which i dont want to do i can not write same code multiple times

Comment: it is literally 2-3 lines of code. your project will survive if the logic dictates you need to have the service call within a subscribe and outside of one.

Comment: if your notifications are long, you can break it out into a different method so that you are fully duplicating code. But there is no way to reliably do what you want to without calling the function in two separate places.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I am new but rhavelka is right, and if you don't want to write the same code twice, just put it in a method.